# Scheduler that delegates jobs to various clients

Tags: python, scheduled-tasks

I hava a simple task that I want to use some kind of scheduler for.
Here is a break up of the problem.

1.) Two or more machines waiting on too take on a job.
2.) list of jobs that need to get executed.

Start the scheduler.
Check if machine one has no job, the send first item in the list to it.
Check if machine two has no job, the send the next item in the list to it.

If machine two finish before machine one, notify back to scheduler, which then sends the third item in the list to machine two.

Repeat this scenario until list is empty.

This is the code I have come up with, this works, but how do I delegate between the functions?

```
import logging
import threading
import time

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG,
                    format='[%(levelname)s] (%(threadName)-10s) %(message)s',
                    )

def worker1(job):
    logging.debug('Starting: %s' % job)
    time.sleep(7)
    logging.debug('Exiting: %s' % job)
    return

def worker2(job):
    logging.debug('Starting: %s' % job)
    time.sleep(3)
    logging.debug('Exiting: %s' % job)
    return


if __name__ == '__main__':
    jobs = ['job1', 'job2', 'job3', 'job4', 'job5']

    #t1 = threading.Thread(target=worker1, args=(job, ))   
    for job in jobs:
        try:
            t1 = threading.Thread(target=worker1, args=(job, ))
            t1.start()
            t1.join()
            #Thread(target=myfunction, args=(job,)).start()
        except Exception, errtxt:
            print errtxt
```

Comment: Have you looked at Celery?  http://www.celeryproject.org/